# Recurrence or transience of the 1-3 tree

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

The 1-3 tree is a rooted tree with only the root at level n=1, and from thereafter, $2^n$ vertices at each tier of distance from the root.  However, they are not connected as in the binary tree.  Put the root at the bottom, and as you go up in $n$, at each level draw the $2^n$ vertices from left to right. bAt each level $k$ the connections are drawn towards level $k+1$ so that there are $3$ edges coming out of each of the right half and $1$ edge coming out of each of the left half of the $2^k$ vertices.  The endpoint of these edges within the level $k+1$ is determined so that there are no crossings.

Why is simple random walk on this graph transient? (Or is it actually recurrent, and why?)

This question arises here: http://pages.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/book.pdf

It does not arise explicitly, but it is my hopeful answer to exercise 3.4 and 3.5 on p.89.

I have tried to calculate the effective resistance, and I have tried to demonstrate that the flow that starts at the top equally distributed and ends up doing whatever it has to to get to the bottom (root) has energy bounded in $n$.  No success here.  The tree in question can be found drawn on p.5.

Comment: Two bits of minor nitpickery: (1) should the root be at level 1 or level 0? (2) what is the degree of the root? My presumption is that the root is at level 0 and of degree 2, respectively, but it's not clear in the Q.  Also, this is a fascinating tree; do you have more references to it?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Your presumption is right.  Unfortunately, I don't have any references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I can use the same technique as was used to show that the branching number is $1$ in order to show that the tree walk is actually recurrent.  Thus it does not provide an answer to either exercise 3.4 or 3.5.  Namely, any flow with finite energy, which we assume exists for a contradiction, would have to send nonzero flow down the right most branch or nonzero flow somewhere else.  Either case is a contradiction.