# Examples of transient and recurrent simple random walks on trees

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

This is a followup to [Recurrence or transience of the 1-3 tree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096903/recurrence-or-transience-of-the-1-3-tree/1096988#1096988) in which I discovered that my original guess of an example for some exercises was wrong. (Those exercises can be found in http://pages.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/book.pdf exercise 3.4 and 3.5)

Here I will reproduce the questions.  My previous question itself, as well as what I said I did there, show my existing efforts toward solution.

Please show an example of the following or show they don't exist:

1. A rooted tree with branching number $1$ that has transient simple random walk.
2. A rooted tree that has the random walk that steps to a child with probability $1/br(T)$ as much as the probability of stepping to the parent (i.e. the distance from the root is a simple random walk) that is transient.
3. A tree with lower growth=$\liminf_n |T_n|^{1/n}>1$ where $T_n$ is the vertices at distance $n$ from the root that is recurrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, we can modify the binary tree by inserting superexponentially many generations with only 1 child.  Transience is maintained, but the branching number is reduced to 1.  This handles the second. The 1-3 tree discussed in the previous question suffices for the 3rd question.

Comment: I'm currently struggling to understand the case 1. in your question above - whether there exists a tree with branching number 1 having a transient simple random walk. I just tried to verify that the modified binary tree is transient, but I'm quite confident now that it actually is recurrent - I calculated the probability that level n is reached before returning to the root for the first 8 levels with a program and identified the corresponding sequence of fractions using OEIS (only using the first 5 levels, and it agreed on the remaining 3 on all decimal digits). The sequence converges to 0.

Comment: (with levels, I mean the original levels in the binary tree, so the last finite subtree I calculated the probabilities for had actually a depth of 135; in addition, I only added exponentially many generations with only 1 child (and it already became recurrent, apparently)) Do you have any more insights on case 1. of your question or do you think I'm wrong and made a mistake in my calculations?

Comment: Nevermind, see my answer on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434254/simple-random-walk-on-infinite-tree-recurrence-transience for more details.